# How can i create a Node.js bluemix app that can use php to call a database binded as service to the same app

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ibm-cloud

I know how to create a node js app that has a database as a service, but how can i add php files to write and read from this service database? 
I can add php files to the project without doing anything else? and if so, what's an example of the credentials used for the connection? thank you

Comment: Do you want to create a php app and call it from Node.js or do you want to execute php from within Node.js?

Comment: execute php from within node.js

Comment: Not sure that you can invoke php directly, but you could have two apps on the same machine. Your Node.js would then call into a php-based api. Something like here (regarding deployment): https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-ContextPathRouting/